# How to achieve autocomple query with query dsl (elasticsearch)?

Tags: autocomplete, elasticsearch

How can i achieve autocompleter search/results withh query dsl (QueryBuilder) ?
[(api link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/query-dsl-queries.html))

Want to achieve search like :
search keyword "John D"

result:

"John Daa"

"John Derm"

"John Deerms"

---

I tried to use "match" and "multi match" with "phrase_prefix" type, it almost did the job but there is something wrong, since results are :

for keyword "John D" - only "John Daa" is shown, other two are missing, do not understand this part much.

for keyword "John De" - Shown are "John Derm", "John Deerms" which is OK .

Comment: Did you try autocomplete API - Auto comeplete API would be a better performane and functioanility option here - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html

Comment: Not sure if i understand this well, but at indexing stage i would have to manually entry values for "output" for exact "inputs" . That is not very option for me since i have about 800k entries. I would like to be able autocomplete search in them.

Comment: Yes , you will need to do that. But the speed is really awesome.

Comment: hmm i did set - "max_expansions" from 10 to 1000, now searches contains also other items in search, it looks good will tets it further. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is solved by [completion suggester](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html).

Comment: As Vineeth Mohan already mentioned i would have to mannualy add entry values for "output" at indexing phase. Thats impossible for me since i have data in thousands.

Comment: thousands of records is small amount of data in terms of elasticsearch. If you're able to change code that feeds data into index - do a change and make re-indexing script that would take care of the "output" values tailored to your use-case.